# A backup user with specific permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, centos

I need to create a user on my CentOS box which is only allowed to run a couple of commands:

- lvcreate
- lvremove
- mount
- kpartx
- rdiff-backup

And access to all files in `/dev/` and `/mnt`. How do I set this up? The commands need to ran as root, but if someone is able to get access to the machine (somehow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this using:

```
Cmnd_Alias      COMMANDS = /usr/sbin/lvcreate, /usr/sbin/lvremove, /sbin/kpartx, /usr/sbin/lvdisplay, /usr/bin/rdiff-backup, /bin/mount, /bin/umount
backupvps       ALL=NOPASSWD: COMMANDS
```